# Change Passcode on aes_encrypt with a query

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update

I am trying to start a query which updates the secret key with the original value.
Searching for a query which takes the pass1 value, decrypt it with the old passcode and encrypt it again with the new passcode.

In the database the table looks like this:

MySQL v5.1.61

**table1**: id, pass1

```
UPDATE table1
SET pass1 = (aes_encrypt(SELECT aes_decrypt(pass1,'oldpasscode') WHERE id= ),'newpasscode') ...?
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
UPDATE table1
SET pass1 = aes_encrypt(aes_decrypt(pass1,'oldpasscode'),'newpasscode');
```